# How to approach creating a Spring Boot backend which follows requests like a browser to set cookies?

Tags: spring-boot, http, cookies

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot backend which is able to make requests to this [url](https://www.dhl.de/de/privatkunden/pakete-empfangen/verfolgen.html). When requesting this url with a fresh browser window, aprox. 50 requests are made.

I managed to saved the cookies from the first request to the above url, but how do I approach following the follow-up requests from the browser, which are often triggered by javascript code, to set all the cookies? Is there an easy way?

My approach is to request all the urls which set cookies manually using my network recording. Is there a better, automatic way? Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the request with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) in headless mode to achieve what you need with very little effort.